# Imagebutton one on top of another can't click the one underneath the other - Scene2d LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I have two **ImageButtons** one on top of the other. Depending on events in my game I fadeOut one of the buttons and fadeIn the other, and vice versa. The problem is that the buttons are placed in a Stack at exactly the same position and the button underneath does not receive the click event. How can I temporarily stack it on top of the other one that is fadedOut so it receives the click event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`toFront()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/) method of `Actor`. Then it should receive the events.